# Is there a custom y-axis for graph2d visualizations?

Tags: vis.js

I would like custom intervals for the y-axis.  The (`dataAxis.left.format`) function seems to only alter the value label not the value itself.

I tried using the  (`dataAxis.left.range.max`) to set the max on the graph and still no luck adjusting the labeling.

Any help would be appreciated!